# how to print a pattern using 1's in the form of plus sign using numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pattern-matching

How to print a plus pattern with 1's inside zeros using numpy array!! I need to satisfy all the cases.I tried below code!!

Code:

```
n = int(input())
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)
x[3:4] = 0
x[2:-1,2:3] = x[1:-1,2:3] = x[2:3] = x[0:-1,2:3] = x[4:,2:3]= 1
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(x[i][j] , end = " ")
    print()
```

output:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you add more detail to your question? What do you mean "satisfy all cases"? What is your expected output, and how is that different than your current output?

Comment: Is there limitations to what "n" might be? i.e. can it be an even number? or must be odd, what does "all cases" mean?

Comment: input can be any number like 1 or 2 or 3 .. but there should be a plus pattern of 1 inside 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with broadcasting using an array where the middle element is 1 (or True):

```
n = int(input("size: "))
import numpy as np

r = np.arange(n)==n//2
r = r*1 | r[:,None]
print(r)
```

output:

```
size: 5
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

explanation:

```
r = np.arange(n)==n//2
```

produces an array of True/False where the middle point (indice n//2) is True and all other entries are false:

```
[False, False, True, False, False]
```

If you convert this 1x5 array to a shape of 5x1 using `r[,:None]` you get

```
[[False],
 [False],
 [ True],
 [False],
 [False]]
```

Multiplying these True/False values by 1 converts them to numbers and the binary or operator `|` will keep the ones in the middle line and middle column when each row is broadcasted over each column:

```
(OR)  0 0 1 0 0
    -----------
 0  | 0 0 1 0 0
 0  | 0 0 1 0 0
 1  | 1 1 1 1 1
 0  | 0 0 1 0 0
 0  | 0 0 1 0 0
```

Note that there are a multitude of ways to achieve this.

Here's another example:

```
np.max(np.indices((n,n))==n//2,axis=0)*1
```

Comment: Can you please explain the same??

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption is:**
**Input:** Given a single positive odd integer 'n' greater than 2.

Below is the code:

#Read the input

```
n = int(input())
```

#Import the NumPy package

```
import numpy as np
```

#Create an (n x n) array with all zeros

```
arr = np.zeros((n, n), dtype = int)
```

#Make the middle row and middle column all 1s

```
arr[n//2, :] = 1

arr[: , n//2] = 1
```

#Print the final value of arr

```
print(arr)
```

#The Whole Code is Below:

```
n = int(input())
import numpy as np 
arr = np.zeros((n, n), dtype = int)
arr[n//2, :] = 1
arr[: , n//2] = 1
print(arr)
```

Sample output for n=3:

```
[[0 1 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [0 1 0]]
```

Sample output for n=5:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Sample Output for n=7:

```
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution where you have a zero array and simply set the middle row and column to 1:

```
n = int(input())
a = np.zeros((n,n)).astype(int)
a[n//2,:]=a[:,n//2]=1
print(a)

[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Comment: why we use floor division here?

Comment: @Kishan if your n is odd (like n=5), n/5=2.5, but indexing has to be integer, either 2 or 3 should be used for indexing in the example of 5. `//` operator returns integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Read the input
n = int(input())

# Import the NumPy package
import numpy as np 

# Write your code here
arr = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)

for i in range(n):
  arr[i,-n//2] = 1 # fill 1 in every row with middle column

arr[-n//2,] = 1 # fill 1 at middle row in every column
print(arr)
```